# Simplify jQuery code by naming and recalling a repeated snippet

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

Sorry this question is so "newbie." I'm not entirely sure if what I'm attempting to do is possible, but I thought I would check.

I have a script that finds and operates on many different elements inside of an iframe, like so:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    $('#iframe').contents().find('target1').doSomething1();
    $('#iframe').contents().find('target2').doSomething2();
    $('#iframe').contents().find('target3').doSomething3();
    $('#iframe').contents().find('target4').doSomething4();
    $('#iframe').contents().find('target5').doSomething5();
    $('#iframe').contents().find('target6').doSomething6();
    $('#iframe').contents().find('target7').doSomething7();
    $('#iframe').contents().find('target8').doSomething8();
    $('#iframe').contents().find('target9').doSomething9();
    ...

});
```

What I would like to do, if possible, is make the code shorter and more readable by defining and recalling `$('#iframe').contents().find()` as a shorter expression of some sort. Something like this:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    function iframe(){
        $('#iframe').contents().find()
    }

    iframe('target1').doSomething1();
    iframe('target2').doSomething2();
    iframe('target3').doSomething3();
    iframe('target4').doSomething4();
    iframe('target5').doSomething5();
    iframe('target6').doSomething6();
    iframe('target7').doSomething7();
    iframe('target8').doSomething8();
    iframe('target9').doSomething9();

});
```

Obviously, that example doesn't work. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: Yes it is. You probably benefit the most from learning the basics about functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: -1 You should be more specific about `doSomething1()` to `doSomething9()`, because this will magnificently affect the answer.

Comment: No, I shouldn't have been more specific. My question was regarding how to define and recall a function with a parameter passed to it, and it was answered to my satisfaction. I don't doubt that posting my entire 150+ line script for open critique would reveal many other opportunities for optimization, but that would be 1) inappropriate for the Q&A format of StackExchange and 2) well beyond the scope of the single question to which I was trying to find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure - you just need a function. You were part of the way there, but you need to specify and use a parameter.

Example:

```
function iframe(target) {
    return $('#iframe').contents().find(target);
}

$(window).load(function(){
  iframe('target1').doSomething1();
  iframe('target2').doSomething2();
  iframe('target3').doSomething3();
  iframe('target4').doSomething4();
  iframe('target5').doSomething5();
  iframe('target6').doSomething6();
  iframe('target7').doSomething7();
  iframe('target8').doSomething8();
  iframe('target9').doSomething9();

});
```

Note that the function can (and probably should) be defined outside of the `.load` handler. Also, it's very likely you can simplify this even more, but it's hard to tell without knowing what `doSomething1`, `doSomething2`, etc., actually do.

Answer (score 1):

This is what a function is for. You're actually much closer than you realize, you just need your function to accept a parameter and return a result:

```
function iframe(selector){
   return $('#iframe').contents().find(selector);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

keep it simple and silly.

As the one who asked the question said that he is newbie in functions, I suggest this easy-to-understand solution.  Then he will know what to do to make shorter and faster after becoming advanced in JQuery. 
Otherwise, he will use the advanced solutions without understanding them. Add on that if he get used to use code that he does not exactly know what it actually does.

```
 $(window).load(function(){
    iFrame('#id1');
    iFreme('#id2');
    ...
    });

function iFrame(x)
{

if(x=='#id1')
{
      $('#iframe').contents().find($(x)).doSomething();

}
else if (x=='#id2')
{
      $('#iframe').contents().find($(x)).doSomethingElse();

}
...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd actually argue in favor of the following:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $contents = $('#iframe').contents();
    $contents.find('target1').doSomething1();
    $contents.find('target2').doSomething2();
    $contents.find('target3').doSomething3();
    $contents.find('target4').doSomething4();
    $contents.find('target5').doSomething5();
});
```

The reason being the find on the contents() is a smaller scope search than the $('#iframe') search.  Alternatively you could also do

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $targets = $('#iframe').contents().find('target1, target2, target3, target4, target5');
    $targets.filter('target1').doSomething1();
    $targets.filter('target2').doSomething2();
    $targets.filter('target3').doSomething3();
    $targets.filter('target4').doSomething4();
    $targets.filter('target5').doSomething5();
});
```

This has the added benifit of doing the finds once and then filtering on the result array to find the object to operate on, rather than doing a find on the contents dom for each target to execute on.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var i = 1,
        $contents = $('#iframe').contents();

    for (; i < 10; i++) {
        $contents.find('target' + i)['doSomething' + i]();
    }
});
```